# Show all leader mappings

Tags: vim

I have a some command set up in my `.vimrc` for mapping `,r`.

But when I press `,r`, vim does not trigger a command immediately but waits a while so I can type more characters. That means I have something set up for longer mapping, e.g. `,re` or `,rt`.

I don't use any mapping like that, nor see any `<leader>rX` mappings in my `.vimrc`. Looks like some plugin is setting it.

Is there a way to show all leader mappings to figure out what mapping is that?

Comment: Try if simply `:map` can be enough for you. It show all current mappings, including those that begin with `<leader>`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I commented it because I though you were looking for something more complex. Already put it as answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try with `:map` command. It shows all current mappings including those created with `<leader>`.

Answer (score 22):

On my system (vim 7.3 on OS X)

```
:map ,r
```

shows all mappings *starting* with `,r`

Comment: Also very great! Thank you. I've already accepted Birei's answer but I hope you get some thumbs up.

Comment: Also `:map <leader>` works. Case you are not sure which character is.

Answer (score 19):

The output of `:map` can be a bit too long. Refining the question gives better results:

```
:verbose map <leader>  " all mapping in all modes that use <leader>, 
                       " and where they are defined
:verbose map <buffer>  " all mappings defined for the current buffer,
                       " and where they are defined
:verbose nmap <leader> " all normal mode mappings that use <leader>,
                       " and where they are defined
```

More info:

```
:h :map
```